# Phpstorm подменить определение методов

Tags: php, phpdoc

Каким образом можно указать phpstrom с помощью phpdoc правильные возвращаемые типы у классов из vendor?

Например `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security->getUser` возвращает `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`

А я бы хотел `\App\Entity\User`

Про phpdoc вида

```
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $context->getEntity()->getInstance();
```

В курсе, нужно другое решение

Answer (score 0):

чтобы корректно подсвечивалось. Файл например в src/Helper/Security.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core;

if (\class_exists(Security::class)) {
    $t = 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core';
    \class_alias(Security::class, $t . '\Security');
} else {
    /**
     * @method \App\Entity\User|null getUser()
     */
    class Security extends \Security
    {
    }
}
```